ActivityXamlServices.Load takes half an hour
In a windows service, in some situations a workflow is loaded using the method
ActivityXamlServices.Load.
After service startup, the loading does not take more than a second. Later, sometimes loading the same workflow takes more than 30 minutes. The workflow refers to custom activities and is about 100 kB.
How can I get rid of this huge delay resp. identify the source of the delay?
